# Why isn't my jQuery for changing the background color of my div with animation changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I have this code fire when the document is ready:

```
$(".contact input[type='submit']").click(function() {
    $(".contact").animate({"background":"#55bf31"}, 1000);
});
```

And I have the following code in the `head` of my HTML document:

```
        <script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

What's stopping this code from firing? This is how my CSS (well, SASS) is set for my background:

```
.contact {
    @include background(linear-gradient(#3e72ab, #39699d));
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    height: 500px;
```

Comment: @mattcurtis: He has included jQuery UI though... Is it the full version or custom?

Comment: @elclanrs You're right, nice catch. My mistake.

Comment: I wonder is it the only handler for what looks like `submit` essentially.

Comment: Could you post a demo to reproduce the problem? So far it looks like it should work...

Comment: is the button inside a form?

Comment: Probably the page is submitted to itself, if the `input` is inside a form element, prevent the form submission.

Comment: I believe that colors aren't animated in jQuery. There are a couple of libraries out there that might help, such as https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color.

Comment: Color animation don't work by default, you need to include a plugin for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(".contact").animate({"backgroundColor":"#55bf31"}, 1000);
```

Or:

```
$(".contact").animate({"background-color":"#55bf31"}, 1000);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xdytA/